# Reload the page after mailform contact.php success

Tags: php, mail-form

Reload the page after mailform contact.php success.. :(

and i used the validate.js.. 
validate.js.  is this a problem?

I'm sorry, but I'll show you the code. plz

html

```
 <form id="contactform" action="contact.php" method="post" class="validateform" name="send-contact">
   <div id="sendmessage">
      thanks
   </div>
   <div class="controls">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
               <input type="text" name="subject" data-rule="subject" data-msg="" placeholder="hi~"/>
               <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12">
         <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-send" value="Send message" >
      </div>
   </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

contact.php

```
<?php

$headers = array('Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8";', 
    "From: ". $_POST['name'] . "<". $_REQUEST['email'].">", 
); 

mail($sendTo, $subject, $emailText, implode("\n", $headers));

$responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $okMessage);

catch (\Exception $e) {
   $responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $errorMessage);
}

if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
   $encoded = json_encode($responseArray);

   header('Content-Type: application/json');

   echo $encoded;
}
else {
   echo $responseArray['message'];
}
```

and finally code

```
$(function () {

$('#contact-form').validator();

$('#contact-form').on('submit', function (e) {
    if (!e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
        var url = "contact.php";

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (data)
            {
                var messageAlert = 'alert-' + data.type;
                var messageText = data.message;

                var alertBox = '<div class="alert ' + messageAlert + ' alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' + messageText + '</div>';
                if (messageAlert && messageText) {
                    $('#contact-form').find('.messages').html(alertBox);
                    $('#contact-form')[0].reset();
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
})
        });
```

What's the problem?
Reload the page after mailform contact.php success.. :(

and i used the validate.js.. 
validate.js.  is this a problem?

I'm sorry, but I'll show you the code. plz

Comment: What is your exactly problem. be specific.

Comment: if you doing ajax request to server side, its means that you should do reload page inside the `.js` regarding your server side response.

Comment: Dude its an AJAX call and ajax is against page reload or redirect.

Comment: If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers. Btw you can clearly see the other answer is just a copy of mine.

Answer (score 0):

To reload a page after an ajax call, you can use this, put it into your ajax call:

```
location.reload();
```

With your code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    success: function (data)
    {
        var messageAlert = 'alert-' + data.type;
        var messageText = data.message;

        var alertBox = '<div class="alert ' + messageAlert + ' alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' + messageText + '</div>';
        if (messageAlert && messageText) {
            $('#contact-form').find('.messages').html(alertBox);
            $('#contact-form')[0].reset();
        }

        location.reload();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`location.reload();`

Use this code